# Explaination for Multiplayer Game Working(Ludo) using flutter

Tags: flutter

Can someone explain how in ludo all the players in a room are moved to another screen when the host starts the game,
I need to create a similar type of application using flutter development, I created different users who join a room through a code and the data is a collection of documents, each denoting a player in firestore.

Unable to understand how to initiate the next screen for all the players in the room through button click.

Comment: have you solved the issue or not?